# Clickable show/hide accordion menu using CSS

Tags: css, menu, hide, accordion, show

I'd like some help tweaking this little accordion menu and replace the hover effect with a click effect, that means show/hide whenever I click on it, instead of just hovering over it.

http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/04/accordion-menu-css3-transition.html

I don't really know much about CSS, everything I've learned has just been on-the-fly, but this is too hard for me. I've looked into other options such as :target but I don't think you can use it to show and hide at the same time.

Comment: You should start by getting something up on http://jsfiddle.net/, get it as far as you can, and then ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

try to use jquery .slideDown() http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/ , .slideUp() http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/ and .slideToggle() http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/.

Answer (score 0):

you can take your css selectors

```
#accordion div:hover {...} and #accordion div:hover a {...}
```

and replace them with

```
#accordion .item.active {...} and #accordion .item.active a {...}
```

then add click functionality with jQuery

```
$('#accordion').on('click', '.item', function(){
   $('.item').not(this).removeClass('active');
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

and you are done. For complete code

https://jsfiddle.net/logiccanvas/ntgcj0mf/